# Ansible playbook handlers not being executed

Tags: ansible

Any idea why below handlers not executed?, I just want to check if server kernel is 2.6 or 3.10 then will write in a file the servername and compliant (satisfy kernel is 2.6 or 3.10) or non compliant (satisfy kernel != 2.6 or != 3.10)

expected output:
servera compliant
serverb compliant
serverc non compliant

Here is my playbook
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WQ51.png)

Comment: Hi. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and pay attention to the paragraph about pasting code and output as images. You can then edit your question, include the code directly and format it correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Just a hint so you can try to go further before you edit your question: `debug` will never report `changed` so your handlers will never be notified.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious why do not use use your handlers as task directly?

Comment: to call the if else like statement , is there another approach ?